# Explanation for coloring of variables by code editor?

Tags: color, variable

I was working on some homework just now, and I realized that some of my variables have different colors, and I am not sure why.

In the example below `f` is black, and `r` is blue -- but they are very similar to each other.  Can someone please explain why these two variables have different colors, and what the difference means?

Also, I realize that you can change the colors, so please don't go into detail about that.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot has a gap in between line 132 and 136. If you want a real explanation of why `r` is blue after line 132, you have to post the actual, copyable  code sequence *without gaps* that leads to the coloring you are showing here.

Comment: Actually, the scroll bar shows that the notebook doesn't end at `Out[139]`, so it is not unlikely that the reason for `r` being blue is somewhere down. Of course it might just as well have been erased from the notebook altogether, or even have been executed in another notebook (without using the option of having separate contexts).

Answer (score 5):

To find the explanation for the different colors, just highlight the symbol of interest, and go to the menu item `Help > Why the Coloring?...`.

This will tell you that those symbols whose value *has not been defined* will appear blue by default. On the other hand, `f` for example starts out blue before you press shift-return, and changes to black once you define it. That is also why built-in function names including $\mathbb{e}$ are black: they are symbols that already have a definition.

If you define a variable such as `f` and later decide to do `Clear[f]`, or `Remove[f]`, or `f = .` then the definition is removed and the syntax coloring turns back to blue for **all** occurrences of that symbol in the notebook, even in passages that have been evaluated previously.

Comment: Thanks.  But then why is r still blue, because it has been definited.  A long with drx, dry, x, and y

Comment: I can't tell from the screenshot what happened in your notebook between the point when `r` was defined and when it reappears later. It may have been cleared in the meantime. Once a variable is subjected to `Clear`, `Remove` or `=.` it will again be undefined and appear blue **everywhere in the notebook**, even at earlier points. But *sometimes* it does happen that *Mathematica* doesn't immediately recognize a previously defined symbol and incorrectly leaves it blue.

Comment: Strange, I did not clear R.  The notebook is still open and all those variables (which are defined) are still blue.

Comment: What happens when you check the definition of `r` by doing `??r` ?

Comment: Maybe your Kernel crashed?

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy Are you using a notebook specific context or is this all in Global? If the former, then this is not unusual.